# JavaScript Cookie Creation Issue

Tags: java, javascript, google-chrome, cookies

I am currently trying to create a cookie in JavaScript. The idea is that when the user clicks the extension icon whilst watching a YouTube video it gets the tab name and saves it as a cookie. This is so that I can then access the cookie from my Java program.

I am using chrome and I can't see the cookie in the list when I have pressed it even though the alert successfully displays so I am wondering if anyone can see an issue with my code.

Also if anyone has a better idea of how to get the tab name to my Java program I would be happy to hear your ideas.

Thanks everyone, here's my code:

```js
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(run);

function run()
{
    var cookieName, cookieValue;

    cookieName = "Tab";
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab)
    {
       cookieValue = tab.title;
       createCookie(cookieName, cookieValue);
   });
   }

function createCookie(name, value)
{
    var expires = new Date().getTime() + (1000 * 3600);
    var domain = ";domain=.youtube.com";
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + ";expires=" + expires + domain +         ";path=/";
    alert(name + " = " + value + ". Date = " + expires);
}
```

EDIT: I have changed my code to use the chrome API's provided by Google, great success!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has the same problem I have used the Google API's for chrome concerning cookies.

My new code is the following:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(run);

function run()
{
    var cookieName, cookieValue, cookieURL;
    cookieName = "Tab";
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab)
    {
        cookieValue = tab.title;
        cookieURL = tab.url;
        createCookie(cookieName, cookieValue, cookieURL);
    });
}

function createCookie(cookieName, cookieValue, cookieURL)
{
    chrome.cookies.set({name: cookieName, value: cookieValue, domain: ".youtube.com", url: cookieURL});
}
```

Note: In the manifest file you will need permissions for tabs, cookies and the website domain. Furthermore I have not stated when the cookie expires thus it expires when the session is closed.